# CasperJs with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, phantomjs, casperjs, aws-lambda

I use [node-casperjs-aws-lambda](https://github.com/narainsagar/node-casperjs-aws-lambda) to create my casperjs, I update the phantomjs version to 2.1.1 and I deploy the code with the basic example on Lambda, that works perfectly

But When I try to test casperJs with Amazon website it didn't work. The page does not load but in local, it's work:

```
// Simple Javascript example
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.options.verbose = true;
casper.options.logLevel ="debug";

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0');

var amazonProduct = 'https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B017DBB1S8';

console.log('Loading a web page: ' + amazonProduct);
// Ouvre la page produit
casper.start(amazonProduct, function() 
{
    this.echo('Page title is: ' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

The Cloud Watch debug mod give me :

```
Loading a web page: https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B017DBB1S8

2017-01-31T22:04:30.553Z    
[36m[info][0m [phantom] Starting...
[36m[info][0m [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[32;1m[debug][0m [phantom] opening url: https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B017DBB1S8, HTTP GET
[32;1m[debug][0m [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B017DBB1S8, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true

2017-01-31T22:04:31.190Z    [32;1m[debug][0m [phantom] url changed to "https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B017DBB1S8"

2017-01-31T22:04:43.074Z    [32;1m[debug][0m [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false

END RequestId: 3b415fbd-e801-11e6-9736-75ef38e95128

Duration: 15001.48 ms   Billed Duration: 15000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 74 MB
```

I didn't understand the problem (I tried too with the original phantomjs version 1.9.8 given with the package, but I have the same problem)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a timeout problem.

I needed to adjust my timeout in configuration > advanced settings > timeout

Comment: FYI. When I was writing crawler for amazon website, I just found that amazon website was blocking my request so I used Tor to dynamically switch over IPs.